# Use Jest to mock functions in functional React component, Jest: Cannot spy the funcName property because it is not a function; undefined given instead

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I have a functional react component, like this:

```
export default function Component() {

  function funcName() {
    ...
  }

}
```

And I am using Jest and React testing library and I want to test if the function is called when button is clicked. And my test is as below: (I am also using MockedProvider for my Apollo mocks)

```
it('test render', async () => {

const funcName = jest.spyOn(Component, 'funcName')

const { getByTestId } = render(
    <MockedProvider mocks={[data]} addTypename={false}>
    <Component />
    </MockedProvider>
)
await act(async () => {
    await wait(0)
})

fireEvent.change(getByTestId('testId'), { target: { value: 'something' } })
fireEvent.click(getByTestId('button'))
expect(funcName).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

})

I am getting error **Jest: Cannot spy the funcName property because it is not a function; undefined given instead**

I have also tried with Enzyme using wrapper.instance(), or spyOn(Component.property,'funcName') but still get the same error.

And I have also tried with:

```
funcName = jest.fn()
const { getByTestId } = render(
    <MockedProvider mocks={[data]} addTypename={false}>
    <Component funcName={funcName} />
    </MockedProvider>
)
await act(async () => {
    await wait(0)
})
fireEvent.change(getByTestId('testId'), { target: { value: 'something' } })
fireEvent.click(getByTestId('button'))
expect(funcName).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

But this way the test result fails saying funcName is not called at all.

Any idea? Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Can you move this function to another file? That way you can stub/spy/mock it a lot easier. Also another strategy is to test the results of the click, as in what happens to state/props/etc after the click has occurred.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. For this function, it is inner and we do not want to move it to another file. As for the state/prop, I suppose because I am using a mock Apollo server, it won't have any changes in the state or prop.  But you are right, maybe that is the only way to do so. I should try to make some adjustments.